# Looping through an array of arrays to grab a certain field

Tags: php, json, loops

I have data that looks something like this that has been `var_dump`ed from JSON data:

```
array(50) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(25) "zRQaS3CDJxP9smBLsRueV"
    ["location_id"]=>
    string(13) "MB0ERM1RG123"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(20) "2018-09-18T20:51:52Z"
    ["tenders"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(9) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(24) "JLMuqRK8xuEsqdvVxzMF"
        ["location_id"]=>
        string(13) "MB0ERMJ123"
        ["transaction_id"]=>
        string(25) "zRQaS3CDJ7r9smBLsRueV"
        ["created_at"]=>
        string(20) "2018-09-18T20:51:39Z"
        ["amount_money"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["amount"]=>
          int(3695)
          ["currency"]=>
          string(3) "USD"
        }
        ["processing_fee_money"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["amount"]=>
          int(102)
          ["currency"]=>
          string(3) "USD"
        }
        ["customer_id"]=>
        string(26) "GZWPPDYF696VH2YHVBQH0W"
        ["type"]=>
        string(4) "CARD"
        ["card_details"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["status"]=>
          string(8) "CAPTURED"
          ["card"]=>
          array(3) {
            ["card_brand"]=>
            string(4) "VISA"
            ["last_4"]=>
            string(4) "2089"
            ["fingerprint"]=>
            string(71) "sq-1-8MESPf1Jq5aDfseysKwy1dQjFc6H96bBGUPLaW3oNcE7PC-s3bbL5-LA"
          }
          ["entry_method"]=>
          string(3) "EMV"
        }
      }
    }
    ["product"]=>
    string(8) "REGISTER"
    ["client_id"]=>
    string(36) "9C90F8EB-00C3-44A7-AC87-0F763CC3B"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(25) "7VS91iJI4Wt4HoTSsSzznPr"
    ["location_id"]=>
    string(13) "MB0ERM1RGJ123"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(20) "2018-09-18T20:19:41Z"
    ["tenders"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(8) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(23) "xEiGixQD2qq9AdoXnLD"
        ["location_id"]=>
        string(13) "MB0ERM1RGJ123"
        ["transaction_id"]=>
        string(25) "7VS91iJI4Wt4HoTSsSzznPr"
        ["created_at"]=>
        string(20) "2018-09-18T20:14:40Z"
        ["amount_money"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["amount"]=>
          int(1700)
          ["currency"]=>
          string(3) "USD"
        }
        ["processing_fee_money"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["amount"]=>
          int(0)
          ["currency"]=>
          string(3) "USD"
        }
        ["type"]=>
        string(4) "CASH"
        ["cash_details"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["buyer_tendered_money"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["amount"]=>
            int(2000)
            ["currency"]=>
            string(3) "USD"
          }
          ["change_back_money"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["amount"]=>
            int(300)
            ["currency"]=>
            string(3) "USD"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    ["product"]=>
    string(8) "REGISTER"
    ["client_id"]=>
    string(36) "F2155BFC-CC49-44D3-9C19-6BA4A3F683"
...
```

I need to loop through this data in order to get the `amount_money => amount`. So far I have tried to do it like this:

```
function enumerateData($data){
    $data = json_decode($data, true);
    foreach($data as $i => $item) {
        echo "<p id='$i-transaction' class='transactions'>Amount spent: ".$item[$i]["tenders"][0]["amount_money"]["amount"]."</p>";
    }
}
```

However, when I do this I get a few warnings:

```
[Tue Sep 18 16:13:40 2018] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: transactions in /home/tcd/modules/square/connection.php on line 24
[Tue Sep 18 16:13:40 2018] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'cursor' in /home/tcd/modules/square/connection.php on line 24
[Tue Sep 18 16:13:40 2018] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'tenders' in /home/tcd/modules/square/connection.php on line 24
[Tue Sep 18 16:13:40 2018] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'amount_money' in /home/tcd/modules/square/connection.php on line 24
[Tue Sep 18 16:13:40 2018] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'amount' in /home/tcd/modules/square/connection.php on line 24
```

And it displays like so:

```
Amount spent:

Amount spent: C
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I pull the correct data that I need out of the arrays?

Comment: how are you encoding the data ? can you post a print_r as well ?

Answer (score 0):

`$i` is the index of the array you are parsing through, so it is not an index in the array you are looping through. Getting rid of that should solve your problem

```
function enumerateData($data){
    $data = json_decode($data, true);
    foreach($data as $i => $item) {
        echo "<p id='{$i}-transaction' class='transactions'>Amount spent: ".$item["tenders"][0]["amount_money"]["amount"]."</p>";
    }
}
```

Edited: added curly brackets around the `$i` variable in the string

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by looping through each element if it is an array:

```
function enumerateData($data){
    $data = json_decode($data, true);
    foreach($data as $item) {
        if (gettype($item) == "array") {
            foreach ($item as $i => $element){
                $amountSpent = $element["tenders"][0]["amount_money"]["amount"];
                $transactionType = $element["tenders"][0]["type"];
                $processedAt = $element["created_at"];
                echo "<div class='transactions'>";echo "\n";
                echo "    <p id='transaction-{$i}' class='transactions-p-class'>Time created: {$processedAt}<br>Amount spent: {$amountSpent}<br>Transaction type: {$transactionType}</p>";echo "\n";
                echo "</div>";echo "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```